# Excel 2013: How to display corresponding text instead of numbers in axis labels?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, axis-labels

I've a table of some task's progress, per person and I'd like to plot it on a chart.
Y axis - names
X axis - progress (NA, start, in progress, completed)
and the preferable chart is bars, like that:

### [sample chart and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tekjj.png)

My problems are that I can't substitute the X axis ticks with corresponding words (NA, start...) and I can't fill the bars according to the colors of progress, like in conditional formatting of the data itself. Please help me achieving my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to my questions were answered in two different places:

1. The technique of conditional formatting of the bars is described on [Peltier Tech Blog](https://peltiertech.com/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/).
2. Substitution of X ticks legend is described on [Excel Forum](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1294372-changing-x-axis-ticks-label.html#post5217763) in my thread.

Enjoy!